# What is the main symbol in Isabelle's set operator (‘) :: ('a => 'b) => 'a set => 'b set?

Tags: isabelle

I was wondering what is the symbol `‘` in the Isabelle tutorial main.pdf below (under the section "Set")?

```
(‘)  :: ('a => 'b) => 'a set => 'b set
```

By looking into the symbols tab, the closest in shape I could find is `\<acute>` under the "Unsorted" category. I tried to evaluate the following expression, but it doesn't parse:

```
value "´ (λ(n::nat). n+1) {1,2}"

value "(λ(n::nat). n+1) ´ {1,2}"
```

Can anyone help to explain the usage here and what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the symbol that you are looking for is `, not ‘ or ´. The symbol ` is an infix notation for the constant `image` that is defined in theory `Set.thy` in the main library of Isabelle/HOL. Hopefully, the name of the constant is self-explanatory. For completeness, I restate the definition in this answer:

```
definition image :: "('a ⇒ 'b) ⇒ 'a set ⇒ 'b set"    (infixr "`" 90)
  where "f ` A = {y. ∃x∈A. y = f x}"
```

Thence,

```
value "(λ(n::nat). n+1) ` {1,2}"
```

evaluates to `"{2, 3}" :: "nat set"`, as expected.

Comment: Addendum: `blast`/`auto` are pretty good at working with this most of the time, but sometimes they need a little help. If you want to show that ``x ∈ f`X``, try finding an explicit `y` such that `f y = x` and `y ∈ X`. Then ``f y ∈ f`X`` follows from `imageI`.